# Can I read files from a Pi SD card if I can't log in?

Tags: sd-card

I'm locked out of my Pi box. It only accepts ssh logins with a publickey and my key has been corrupted. Can I remove the SD card and get access to the filesystem?

Comment: Get a second SDCard (so you can boot your system). Get a USB SDCard Reader (so you can read your broken SDCard).

Answer (score 3):

If you have another computer with a Linux operating system available then you can poweroff the RasPi, detach the SD Card, put it into a card reader and attach it to the Linux computer. Now you can mount the SD Card and you have full access to its filesystem. This isn't possible with a default macOS or MS Windows PC, because they can only read the first boot partition which is formatted with **FAT32**. The important second root partition that contains all data, is formatted as **EXT4**, the native filesystem of Linux.

Comment: Thank you. I can mount the SD card on my Mac. However, I'm not sure how to navigate this. Where is the filesystem, for example, the user home directories?

Comment: @dellisny I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the SD Card on any Linux computer (which can be a Pi with another OS).

You can always login with a screen and keyboard.

Comment: Thank you. I can mount the SD card on my Mac. However, I'm not sure how to navigate this. Where is the filesystem, for example, the user home directories?

Comment: A Mac is not a Linux computer